# Can I use "because" and "if" consecutively in a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, subordinate-clauses

This is the sentence in question:

> I would like to be able to make an unlimited number of wishes because if I wish for money, life, and love, I don't have to work and I don't have to be afraid of death.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U You probably want to wait at least a day or two before selecting an answer :-) You may get a much better one! People may not bother to write another answer - or read your question - if you have already selected one.

Comment: Why do you think you wouldn't be able to? Questions asking for grammaticality judgements need to explain why the construction is in doubt.

Comment: I agree with Araucaria about waiting...he has a much better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's absolutely fine to use *because* and *if* consecutively in a sentence.

The word *because* heads a phrase that contains a subordinate clause (some grammars recognise *because* as a preposition, others call it a subordinating conjunction). This phrase has the function of Adjunct in the sentence (read *adverbial*).

Notice that the Adjunct can come before or after the clause that it modifies:

- I left [*because I was going to be very late*].
- [*Because I was going to be very late*], I left.

We can describe the relationship above by saying that the Adjunct is a *dependent* of clause *I left*.

Inside the Adjunct, there is a fully formed finite clause *I was going to be late*. Now, it is perfectly possible for this clause to have its own Adjunct.

Another type of adjunct we can have is a conditional adjunct. In the Original Poster's example, this is a phrase headed by the preposition *if*. The only requirement for this conditional adjunct is a clause for it to modify. In our example, we can use the subordinate clause *I was going to be late*:

- [***if I missed the next train***] *I was going to be very late*
- I left because [[***if I missed the next train***] *I was going to be very late*]

If we put the conditional adjunct before the clause it is modifying it will occur directly after the word *because*. Notice that we could put it afterwards instead:

- I left because [*I was going to be very late* [***If I missed the next train***]].

**The Original Poster's sentence**

The clause that is being modified by the *because*-Adjunct is:

- I would like to be able to make an unlimited number of wishes

The adjunct modifying this clause is:

- because [if I wish for money, life, and love, I don't have to work and I don't have to be afraid of death].

This Adjunct consists of a clause which is being modified by its own conditional adjunct. The clause in question is:

- I don't have to work and I don't have to be afraid of death

The conditional Adjunct, which is a dependent of this clause is:

- if I wish for money, life, and love

We could construe the sentence like this:

- I would like to be able to make an unlimited number of wishes because [[***if I wish for money, life, and love***], *I don't have to work and I don't have to be afraid of death*.]

Comment: Great answer.  In my ESL writing classes I tell my students to remember this: Because SVO, SVO or SVOBecauseSVO...seems to help them avoid making mistakes.  SVO means subject verb object. I'm can't say "complete sentence" or "clause" because many of them have varying ideas of what those are but SVO seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The sentence also works if you switch the phrases around, "...because I don't have to work and I don't have to be afraid of death if I wish for money, life, and love."  The "if" is part of the conditional sentence but what follows the "because" is a complete sentence, so you're ok.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say this is the most mellifluous construction, but you're in good company.  Here's an example from [*Don't Polish Your Ignorance ... It May Shine*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22because%20if%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22because+if%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&start=40) by Sadhguru:

> That is why kriya yoga has been considered the wisest, **because if** you practice it you do not need anybody's cooperation.

Here the reason is a direct proof:  practice this kind of yoga and you achieve wisdom without interference.

From [*Economics*](https://books.google.com/books?id=EGeEMRfsrRsC&pg=PA447&dq=%22because%20if%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEsQ6AEwCTg8ahUKEwi4vN37hunGAhVKMIgKHb_rB54#v=onepage&q=%22because%20if%22&f=false) by Roger A Arnold

> Most people will say that Jeremy will take the $200 and leave the
>   movie theater simply **because if** he doesn't leave, he loses the
>   opportunity to receive $200.

Here the reason after the "because" is an argument from contradiction, i.e., assuming the opposite of the claim in the independent clause, to reach a contradiction in the conclusion, thus validating the original claim:  no one would stay to watch a $10 movie and thereby lose $200.

Your "because" doesn't seem to support your claim.  If you wish for three things ("money, life, and love"), you'll get two things:  leisure and no fear of death.  What happened to love?  And why does getting these two things explain why you want more wishes?  Oh, well.  All you asked about was the grammar.